# JBoss Cli stop a deployment until next startup

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly, jboss-cli

With WildFly 15.0.1 I want to use jboss-cli to stop a deployment, but leave it ready for deployment with the next startup of WildFly.

So far I managed to disable or undeploy it keeping its content (same as disable). But when restarting WildFly, the deployment will continue disabled.

```
deployment enable name
undeploy name --keep-content
```

I tried also creating a file `name.dodeploy` in the deployments folder, but this doesn't work as the deployment was done using the Admin Console.

I know that after restart I could call the enable command, but because of some library link problem we would need that the deployment is started on startup and not triggered later.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want the application to be deployed only while server startup, not after that ? If so, then you have to use the filesystem bade deployment. In the deployment subsystem you can set scan interval as 0 so that deployment directory will be scanned only at server startup time.

Comment: It doesn't need to be just on startup, but at least on startup. The problem with the jboss-cli is that I don't find the way to say "deploy it on next startup, but not now". I managed to make this on the deployments folder by placing a file name.dodeploy when WildFly is stopped. That would be our workaround. I just thought that maybe it was possible to do the same using the console.

Comment: You'd have to execute another CLI command to enable it. How do you restart your server? Is it a manual or automated process?

Comment: The server is restarted with a call to stop the Windows Service. If another CLI command to enable is required after the server is started, I will have to go with the /deployments folder option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we didn't find a way to solve this issue using console deployments and jboss-cli. Our final approach is using the /deployments folder:

1. Deploy artifacts by placing them in the /deployments folder
2. To stop one single deployment, use JBoss CLI to 'disable' that deployment
3. Then, Shutdown WildFly
4. Before starting up WildFly, copy a file deployment-name.dodeploy to the /deployments folder
5. Start WildFly and the deployment will be performed normally on startup